# Fast refreshing a php get with multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, page-refresh

Things to note before reading:

- I am aware the code isn't that brilliant.  Please don't comment on my old work ;)
- I am aware that mysql_query is deprecated. Updating that at the moment isn't within the scope of this question

**Question background**

I got an interesting bug report via an old website today which has caused me a huge amount of concern as I didn't ever expect this bug to occur.

The page is simple.  On the original load a table is displayed after looping through a mysql query to the database.  Each of those rows display a link with:

```
url.com/items.php?use=XXX&confirm=0
```

The XXX relates to the ID of the item in the `items table` in the database.  The confirm=0 has the following code:

```
if(isset($_GET['use'])){

  $id=@mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['use']);

    if(isset($_GET['confirm'])){

      $confirm=@mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['confirm']);

      if($confirm==0){

       // show a confirm button of YES / NO for them 
       // to click which has 1 for confirm
```

The user can then click on YES which transfers them to:

```
url.com/items.php?use=XXX&confirm=1
```

The code then goes to an `else` from the above  code which does the following checks:

```
    if($id<1){
            echo "<p class='error-message'>An error has occurred.</p>";
            print "<p class='center'><a href='http://www.url.com/items.php'>[Back]</a></p>";
            include("inc/ftr.php");
            exit();
        }

        if(empty($id)){
            echo "<p class='error-message'>An error has occurred.</p>";
            print "<p class='center'><a href='http://www.url.com/items.php'>[Back]</a></p>";
            include("inc/ftr.php");
            exit();
        }

        $quantity = 0;
        $result=@mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE item_id=$id AND u_id=$user_id");
        $num_rows=@mysql_num_rows($result);
        $r=@mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $quantity=$r['quantity'];

        if($num_rows==0){
            echo "<p class='error-message'>You do not own any of these.</p>";
            print "<p class='center'><a href='http://www.url.com/items.php'>[Back]</a></p>";
            include("inc/ftr.php");
            exit();
        }

        if($quantity<1){
            echo "<p class='error-message'>You don't have any of these left!</p>";
            print "<p class='center'><a href='http://www.url.com/items.php'>[Back]</a></p>";
            include("inc/ftr.php");
            exit();
        }

        $result=@mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id=$id");
        $r=@mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $type=$r['type'];
        $item_name=$r['item_name'];
```

The above performs the relevant checks to make sure the ID exists and then queries the database to get the current quantity from the inventory and checks it's not below 0.  If it is below 0 then it blocks the page at that point.

The code after this point removes the quantity of the item from the database and implements the "effect" of the item.  Let's just assume an **update** is performed.

**The problem:**
The actual problem I am having here is that if a user refreshes the page multiple times they can actually get the `update` query to perform but they can actually skip the check on the quantity.  The update query is run over and over but the check on the quantity is never run more than once as there are no error messages.  An example today was when I had **3 items** in my inventory and I pressed f5 about 100 times.  I managed to get the query update to run **16 times** without any error message displaying.  If I then waited a few seconds and pressed f5 again it would display an error message saying I didn't have any of those items.

The following solutions are not an option as I don't want to waste time coding:

- Create an ajax call to prevent multiple submits before all queries have been processed.
- Implementing an MVC structure and redirecting the user to a separate page which prevents multiple submits

If anyone could explain the reason for this bug (with relevant reading material) or even offer a solution to resolve it that would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition due to the time between querying the database for the stock level, and a subsequent update to reduce it. If you send several requests very quickly then each will receive the same stock level (3 in this case) before the first request has had time to update the stock level.

You need to change your code such that your `query & decrement` is atomic - i.e. there are no gaps.

One possible solution is to attempt an update, where stock level > 0 and see how many rows are affected.

```
UPDATE products set `stockLevel`=`stocklevel`-1 where `productId` = 'something' and `stocklevel`>0
```

If the number of rows affected is 0, you had no stock. If the number of rows affected is 1 then you had stock. Multiple queries will reduce stock to zero, at which point you should see some error messages.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely due to having multiple concurrent threads running on your web server, responding to requests simultaneously for non-blocking / non-transactional database operations.  Some of the requests may pass the inventory quantity check while other requests are still being processed.

One possible solution would be to use MySQL transactions, but this would probably require migrating to mysqli or PDO which seems to be outside the scope of your desired solution, and require InnoDB tables which you might not have.

Should you ever choose to upgrade to use mysqli, here is some useful information:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

http://coders-view.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-use-mysql-transactions-with-php.html

Another solution would be to implement "locking" functionality.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

```
mysql_query("LOCK TABLES inventory WRITE;");
// all your other PHP/SQL here
mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES;");
```

This will prevent other clients from reading the inventory table while the first client is still busy processing your PHP/MySQL code